# How to efficiently INSERT a large number of rows in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pool of 100 users who have answered a question. Only about 10% of those users will choose the right answer.

I want to create a new table, with a row for every one of the 90% who answered wrong, with their username and the wrong answer they provided.

What is the best way to do that?

Should I first create an array of the usernames who entered the wrong answer, then, do a `foreach` loop, with an INSERT MySQL for each iteration?

Or is there a MySQL way to get the approach "apply to all who have NOT answer right"?

Thanks a lot. Regards

Comment: Do you get all the answers at the same time?  So, in one request?

Comment: Without knowing more I would say you could use prepared statements. Inside the `foreach` you would then execute the statement. Alternatively, `INSERT` supports multiple rows in a single SQL query.

Comment: Hi, yes, I only apply this command when all the users have answered, so it's a one-time command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a table that stores all users and answers, like so:

```
Table : all_answers

  user_id  |  answer
    joe         a
    mary        b
    john        c
```

And the correct answer is a `c`, you can have a similar table (same schema) called `wrong_answers`, and populate it like so:

```
 INSERT INTO wrong_answers 
        SELECT user_id, answer FROM all_answers WHERE answer <> `c`
```

You could also create a trigger to do this for you, or a view.

If you have other values stored in `wrong_answers` (such as a primary key), you would want to indicate which values in `wrong_answers` to populate, like so:

```
INSERT INTO wrong_answers (user,answer)
    SELECT user, answer FROM answers
    WHERE answer <> 'c';
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. 
What if in the table `wrong_answers`, the order of the columns is as follows: `idprimary`,`username`,`answer`. Do I have to use NULL somewhere? THanks a lot

Comment: If the `idprimary` is auto incrementing, you don't need to provide a value, but you will need to indicate that you are only populating the second to fields.  I'll update in just a moment.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest and easiest way to do a lot of single inserts is:

```
INSERT DELAYED
```

Comment: And here's the reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html

Answer (score 2):

Use a multi-insert SQL query, like so:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2), (6, 9), (7, 8)
```

This will let you insert however many rows you need to in a single query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. In the VALUES part of your example, I assume the first digit of each pair would be the username and the second digit would be the answer. Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are correct! So you would do something like `INSERT INTO table1 (username, answer) VALUES ("Nick", "something"), ("Alex", "Something else")`

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into new_table
select (username from old_table where got_it_wrong = 1 )
```